# Java RMI connection refused in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, linux, rmi

Java RMI connection refused in Ubuntu Linux. Client runs on Windows mc and server runs on Linux mc and in `hosts` file of Linux, `127.0.0.1` `localhost` is written and all the lines are commented.

Answer (score 1):

If the client is windows and the server is linux, they are clearly different machines.  Therefore, the client should NOT be using "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 as the hostname / IP address of the server.  They both mean "this machine"; i.e. the client on Windows would attempt to talk to an RMI server on the same Windows machine.

If you attempt to connect to a service that is not running on the machine that the connection attempt goes to, the operating system will "refuse" the connection.  Based on your problem description, that is most likely what is happening here.

Comment: clients is windows mc (192.168.0.100) & server is linux mc (192.168.0.101), the rmi port is 1099. When client calls to server it gets error

Comment: In that case, either the RMI server is not running, or a firewall is blocking access.

Comment: client{192.168.0.100};server1{192.168.0.101};server2{192.168.0.102} is connected over wifi. Client send request to server1. server1 execute & send result to client & send checkpoint to server 2 every time. If server1 fails then server2 execute the remaining operation & send result to client. How server1 can send checkpoint to server2 & server2 can do remaining operation & send result to client. give the java rmi code & execution process by considering "addition of1+1 to n+n".

Comment: Ask a new Question.  By the way, did my Answer answer your original Question?  Of yes, then it is conventional to *accept* the answer.

Comment: yes. Thank you for the answer of previous question. Please solve the new.

Comment: There is an only problem to deserialize the checkpoint from server 1 for both windows and linux.

Comment: Noted.  Did you read my last two comments?  Did you understand them?